# не выполняется проверка на длину строки

Tags: javascript

добавляемая строка должна быть длиной в один символ. на строку любой длины выводит сообщение что необходим один символ.

```js
var terminal = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var term=document.getElementById('terminal').innerHTML = terminal;
var noterminal = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'];
var noterm = document.getElementById('noterminal').innerHTML = noterminal;

function pushTerminal(){
    var x = document.getElementById('newTerminal');
    var str = term.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    var str2 = noterm.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);

    if(str.length == 1 ){
if(str == -1 && str2== -1) {
        term.push(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
        x.innerHTML = term.join();
         }else{
           alert("Элемент уже существует");
        }

    }else{
        alert("Необходимо ввести только один символ!");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
    <div class="terminal">
        <div id="terminal"></div>
        <div id="newTerminal"></div>
        <div class="addTerminal">
              <form>
                <input id ="inputAdd" type="text">
                <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="pushTerminal()">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="noterminal">
       <div id="noterminal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, вы хотели что-то такое?

```js
var terminal = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var term = document.getElementById('terminal').innerHTML = terminal;
var noterminal = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'];
var noterm = document.getElementById('noterminal').innerHTML = noterminal;

function pushTerminal() {
  var x = document.getElementById('newTerminal');
  var termVal = document.getElementById("inputAdd").value;
  var str = term.indexOf(termVal);
  var str2 = noterm.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);

  if (termVal.length == 1) {
    if (str == -1 && str2 == -1) {
      term.push(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
      x.innerHTML = term.join();
    } else {
      alert("Элемент уже существует");
    }

  } else {
    alert("Необходимо ввести только один символ!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
  <div class="terminal">
    <div id="terminal"></div>
    <div id="newTerminal"></div>
    <div class="addTerminal">
      <form>
        <input id="inputAdd" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="pushTerminal()">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="noterminal">
    <div id="noterminal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```